# MySQL 1064 error in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have query

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions ( client_id, name, group_id, type ) 
SELECT clients.id, 'Индивидуал', 0, 1 FROM clients WHERE clients.individual=1;
ALTER TABLE clients DROP COLUMN clients.individual;
ALTER TABLE finance_operations ADD COLUMN sub_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

which works fine in Mysql Workbench.
But if I use it in codeIgniter code:

```
$this->db->simple_query($query);
```

I get error 1064:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ALTER TABLE clients DROP COLUMN clients.individual; ALTER TABLE'
>   at line 4

Comment: I think `simple_query` can do not work with more than one query

Comment: @Jens is right. If you want to execute all of that querys, you need to separet every one in one `$this->db->query($query1);$this->db->query($query2);...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO can not run more than one question one time;
This code is right:

```
$array = [ "query1", "query2", "query3" ];
foreach($array as $query)
    $this->db->simple_query($query);
```